# Ошибка composer Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Установил composer по инструкции со оф. сайта. https://getcomposer.org/download/ Установка прошла без ошибок.

После установки , команда php composer пишет command not found?!

Потом я пытаюсь подтянуть капчу для yii2 вот такой командой

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget" "*"
```

установка начинается , пишет

```
./composer.json has been updated
```

Начинается загрузка, которая проходит успешно, а потом update, при котором появляется ошибка

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


  Problem 1
- himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget 1.0.5 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
- himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget 1.0.6 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
- himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget 1.0.7 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
- himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget 1.1.0 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
- himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget 1.1.1 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
- himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget 1.1.2 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
- himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget 1.2.0 requires yiisoft/yii2 * -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.11.1, 2.0.11.2, 2.0.12, 2.0.12.1, 2.0.12.2, 2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2, 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].
```

И т.д.

вот мой файл composer.json

```
{
"name": "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin",
"type": "application",
"description": "MySQL web administration tool",
"keywords": ["phpmyadmin","mysql","web"],
"homepage": "http://www.phpmyadmin.net/",
"license": "GPL-2.0+",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "The phpMyAdmin Team",
        "email": "phpmyadmin-devel@lists.sourceforge.net",
        "homepage": "http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/team.php"
    }
],
"support": {
    "forum": "https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/discussion/Help",
    "issues": "https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/",
    "wiki": "http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/",
    "source": "https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin"
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0"


},
"require-dev": {
    "satooshi/php-coveralls": "dev-master"
}
```

}

В общем как это поправить и успешно подтянуть google капчу на сайт.
Я в composer новичёк прошу не судите строго.

Comment: 1) В composer.json отсутствует пакет yii2, а он необходим для уснановки этого пакета
2) Проблема может быть в том что yii2 уже установлен (его установленная версия лежит в composer.lock) и не совпадает с необходимой версией

Comment: @lyhoshva да Yii2 уже установлен и работает, тогда как это пофиксить?

Comment: а куда пропал предыдущий composer.json который был при установке Yii?